I am trying to create an application in .NetForms where I read data from a file and then use that data to truncate a chart
Currently I am reading the data from a csv file and displaying it in a textbox on one form. Then I am aiming to pass that data to another form where I can create a visualisation as a column chart where the ethnicity is the X value, and the hourly wage is the Y value. I have tried to include a combobox where the user can select a year to filter the chart by.
CSV: https://www.data.gov.uk/dataset/14fb9401-a320-4633-b1f6-b82f77c5d84b/average-hourly-pay-by-ethnicity
THE PROBLEM: I CANNOT GET MORE THAN ONE BAR ON THE BAR CHART, EVEN THOUGH WHEN DEBUGGING, ALL 10ITEMS ARE PRESENT. THE CHART SHOWS THE FIRST ETHNICITY, "ASIAN", THEN THE PAY, WHEREAS I WANT IT TO SHOW ALL 10 ETHNICITIES. 
I have tried many ways of creating and populating the chart but have gotten no luck, can you guys give any suggestions please? ( I am trying to keep the code as simple as possible, it doesn't have to be of the highest standard)
This is the first form where I am reading the csv and storing the data, I have an option to display the data in the textbox included also.
namespace AS2_U17_5th
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Declaring datalist at the class level
        public static List<DataItems> datalist = new List<DataItems>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ReadDataFromCSV();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // call the display data function
            LoadDataIntoListBox();
        }

        // Removed the redundant declaration of datalist here
        public void LoadDataIntoListBox()
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (DataItems d in datalist)
                {
                    TBData.AppendText($"{d.Year} {d.Ethnicity} {d.HourlyWage}\r\n");

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred while loading data into the ListBox {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        // Method to read data from CSV file
        public static void ReadDataFromCSV()
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("average-hourly-pay.csv"))
                {
                    // Skip header line
                    streamReader.ReadLine();

                    // Looping over remaining lines
                    while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
                        string[] data = line.Split(',');

                        
                        
                            // Parsing data
                            int year;
                            if (!int.TryParse(data[0], out year))
                            {
                                // Log error and continue to next line
                                continue;
                            }

                            string ethnicity = data[1];

                            double hourlyWage;
                            if (!double.TryParse(data[2], out hourlyWage))
                            {
                                // Log error and continue to next line
                                continue;
                            }

                            // make a new object
                            DataItems item = new DataItems
                            {
                                Year = year,
                                Ethnicity = ethnicity,
                                HourlyWage = hourlyWage
                            };

                            // add to list
                            datalist.Add(item);
                        
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred while reading the CSV file: {ex.Message}");
            }

        }





        // Ignore this code
        private void LBLStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void BTNVisualise_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Visualiser CHART = new Visualiser(datalist);
            CHART.Show();
            this.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}

This is the other page where I am using the data and trying to create the chart, using a combobox as a way for the user to filter the information by year.
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace AS2_U17_5th
{
    public partial class Visualiser : Form
    {
        private List<DataItems> datalist;
        public Visualiser(List<DataItems> datalist)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.datalist = datalist;

            // Puts the year in the combobox if anything breaks this should be n1
            CBType.DataSource = datalist.Select(item => item.Year).Distinct().ToList();

            // Setting the primary data type to take from the combobox
            //CBType.SelectedIndex = 0;

            // Creates the chart 
            LoadChartMethod();
        }


        public void LoadChartMethod()
        {
            CHRTVisualisation.Series.Clear();   
            CHRTVisualisation.Series.Add("HourlyWage");

            //Get the seelected year from the Combobox
            int selectedYear = (int)CBType.SelectedItem;

            // Filter the datalist based on the selected year
            List<DataItems> filteredData = datalist.Where(item => item.Year == selectedYear).ToList();

            foreach (var item in filteredData)
            {
                // Add a data point to the chart
                CHRTVisualisation.Series["HourlyWage"].Points.AddXY(item.Ethnicity, item.HourlyWage);
            }


            // Set the labels and the title for the chart
            CHRTVisualisation.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            CHRTVisualisation.Titles.Clear();
            CHRTVisualisation.Titles.Add($"Hourly Wages by Ethnicity - Year {selectedYear}");
            CHRTVisualisation.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = "Ethnicity";
            CHRTVisualisation.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Title = "Hourly Wage";


        }

        private void CBType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadChartMethod();

        }
    }
}




I've done this lots of times working with multiple forms.  Can you explain what issue you are having?  I would add break points to your code and determine what is working and what is not working.  I think part of the issue may be the form is not in the front.  It would take me time to duplicate the project and trying to avoid doing this.  If I did I would like sample of the csv.  I think you would learn more by getting it working with my assistance than for me to do the work.  The code looks very good.  It is just hard for me to determine what is not working just by viewing the code.

Hi, thanks for getting back in touch. I have edited the post. The problem is getting more than one bar to display on the chart.

.AddXY() expects 2 doubles. I can't imagine a double providing insight into "Ethnicity". This falls under "categories" / classification (e.g. bar charts and pie charts), where the x axis (or pie segment) shows a (string) "category" (e.g. Native American).

The following may be of interest: C# identifier naming rules and conventions

The code you posted seems to work for me. However, it's necessary to make some assumptions, since you left out some details. Did you happen to use an AI (such as ChatGPT) to write the code? You have a method named LoadDataIntoListBox(), which contains the following code: TBData.AppendText(...). ListBox doesn't contain an AppendText method, but both RichTextBox and TextBox do. Also you have DataItems, but this is most likely a Class (with properties Ethnicity, HourlyWage, and Year), therefore, it should have a singular name such as DataItem.

Monetary values such as HourlyWage should be stored in a decimal data type.   You have a number of if statements that state: // Log error and continue to next line, but it doesn't appear that there is any code that logs a message. What's the purpose of this.Enabled = false;? It doesn't seem to serve a purpose, and makes the main form unusable. Lastly, you have Visualiser CHART. Why the inconsistency of case? Have you considered using ShowDialog() instead of Show()? The things mentioned above lead me to believe that this code was generated by an AI.

Yeah, a lot of the code was generated by AI, you're correct. This. Enabled = false was meant to deactivate the main form when you open up the second form. I'm not bothered that the log error etc doesn't do anything, I can clean that up later. I'm just struggling to display more than one bar / column on the chart. It just shows Asian, and the pay, then you can filter the year, but I want it to show Asian, black, white etc etc in the chart as separate bars.

Put a break point in the foreach loop and make sure each item is being added : foreach (var item in filteredData)

I have put a break point within the loop, and all I can see is that it's looping through it 11 times, since there are 11 items within the list.  If the code is working for you guys, is there a way that I can see what you guys have created and compare it against mine please?

When I hover over .Points.AddXY, it is showing the desired values being added, i get the screenshot added above, what does this mean?

You didn't specify whether you were using .NET or .NET Framework or the version. I created a  Window Forms App (.NET Framework) v4.8 project.

The version of windows forms charts I was using was bugged, I switched to an older version and it worked straight away.
